# How to send Ctrl+c to telnet socket in php?

Tags: php, sockets, telnet

Here is my php code:
After connection device waits for Ctrl+C before login and password enter.

```
<?php
   $socket = fsockopen("10.120.13.25", "23", $errno, $errstr);
   if($socket)
   {
    print_r ("connected!\n");
   }
     // here device is waiting for Ctrl+C 
   fwrite($socket, Chr(3));  <- not working
   echo("it works"); 
   fclose($socket);
?>
```

I also tried "x03" - no result.

Comment: Did you try flushing (`fflush`)?

Answer (score 0):

So, I did it twice, and got a result:

```
fwrite($socket, "\x03");
fwrite($socket, "\x03");
```